# Further details on pnorm() function in R

Tags: r, statistics

Could someone tell me what are the last two arguments to `pnorm()` mean?

```
set.seed(123)
a <- pnorm(rnorm(10,0,1),0,1)  # rnorm(n=10,mean=0,sd=1) and pnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1)
b <- pnorm(rnorm(10,0,1),0,1,1,0) # however here are two more numbers
```

I could not find via R help or otherwise what the last two digits mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at [the built-in help page for `pnorm`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) , e.g. via typing `?pnorm` ?????

The description of the arguments given there is

```
pnorm(q, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
```

-- so you should read the description of the `lower.tail` and `log.p` arguments, and recognize that 1 will correspond to `TRUE` and 0 to `FALSE`.

Comment: Did you actually look at the help page? Or did you look at it but have a "thinko"?

Comment: Of course I looked into help page! The 0,1 for True/False slipped my mind :)

Comment: In light of your comment the confusion is completely understandable -- if you had written your question including the fact that you had looked specifically at the `pnorm` help page, and including the list of arguments, it would be clearer that your confusion was over the numbers and not (as a quick read of your question might suggest to a jaded R user :-( ) that you are clueless ...